# What to do with unassigned new expression that doesn't need to be assigned

Tags: c#, code-formatting

Small example:

```
class Folder {
    public List<B> Children = new List<B>();
    public string Name;

    public Folder(string name) { Name = name; }
}
class File {
    public Folder Parent;
    public string Name;

    public File(Folder parent, string name) {
        Parent = parent;
        Name = name;
        Parent.Children.Add(this);
    }
}

Folder folder=new Folder("windows");
new File(folder, "notepad.exe"); //<--- this
new File(folder, "regedit.exe"); //<--- and this
```

This is legal reason why not to assign those to any variables. I am worrying about whatever the compiler will optimize out. But more worrying that this code doesn't look like how it should be.

In this situation, what need to do that this code won't look bad?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Also, are those last 3 lines just laid out like that, with nothing containing them?

Comment: @SaverioTerracciano `In this situation, what need to do that this code won't look unprofessional?`, what need to do that those two lines won't be just two new statements on the air. This 3 lines is in some method of course.

Comment: If those 3 lines are in some method, why aren't you showing also the method which contains them? It's still not clear what do you mean by **professional**, if you want some advice about good or bad  practices you'd better give out some more insight on what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @SaverioTerracciano This code is just example I made up. I don't want to accomplish anything on some program, it just happens to me a lot that I have new statements left out like that. I want to get rid of this habbit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably better off here having a factory method on File or a method to add files to folders on the folder object.

For the first:

```
class File
{
    public Folder Parent;
    public string Name;

    public static void Create(Folder parent, string name)
    {
        Parent.Children.Add(new File { Parent = parent, Name = name });
    }
}

var folder = new Folder("windows");
File.Create(folder, "notepad.exe");
File.Create(folder, "regedit.exe");
```

For the second:

```
class Folder 
{
    public List<File> Children = new List<File>();
    public string Name;

    public Folder(string name) { Name = name; }

    public void Add(string name)
    {
        Children.Add(new File { Parent = this, Name = name });
    }
}


var folder = new Folder("windows");
folder.Add("notepad.exe");
folder.Add("regedit.exe");
```

Either pattern will work but the second keeps more true to object oriented design.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler will not "optimize out" your calls to the `File` constructor. However, what you are doing here is not a good idea. It will not be clear from the usage that the `Folder` being passed to the `File` constructor is being modified and is storing the reference to the new `File` so that it is actually not garbage collected.

Consider instead doing something like this:

```
class Folder 
{
    ...

    public void AddFile(string name)
    {
        Children.Add(new File(this, name));
    }
}
```

Comment: I meant that the compiler will optimize out the code itself. But never mind.

Comment: @KugBuBu I understand. If you write `new MyClass(...);` as a standalone statement, it will not be removed by the compiler. However, this is a bad practice, because it isn't clear to someone reading the code why an instance of `MyClass` is being created but not used.